# Script abort because of a possible infinite loop

Tags: xdebug, neoscms

I have followed this instructions to setup the latest version of NEOS:

1. https://docs.neos.io/cms/installation-development-setup/manual-installation-with-a-web-server
2. https://docs.neos.io/cms/installation-development-setup/running-the-setup-tool

After i log into the CMS i get the following error:

```
Xdebug has detected a possible infinite loop, and aborted your script with a stack depth of '256' frames
Exception Code  0
Exception Type  Error
Thrown in File  Packages/Framework/Neos.Flow/Classes/ObjectManagement/ObjectManager.php
Line    539
```

My local environment:

```
PHP Version 7.3.26-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
XDebug 3.0.2
```

what's going wrong here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is simply a repetition of what is already available in the tags. The title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future user of this site who is scanning through a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem, and your current title does not do so.

Answer (score 16):

this solves my problem
20-xdebug.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.max_nesting_level=512
```

php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 600
```

Comment: this is a workaround. not a solution. You or someone just get the problem later.

Comment: then what is the solution, im also facing same issue.

Comment: if i include jquery file via wp_enque methode, this same error comes, but when i hardcode my js file via <script> tag, error goes. but hard code is not good way.

Comment: What is the solution? I've just seen this for the first time too, and doing what suggested here hasn't fixed it... I still get the fatal error??

Comment: This is possible too: ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 512);

Answer (score 3):

On **MacOS** with a **arm64**(M1, M2) processor and **Homebrews PHP 8.1**, open: `/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1/php.ini`

Add to the top of the file:

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"

[PHP]

; Possible values for mode: off,develop,coverage,debug,gcstats,profile,trace
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.max_nesting_level=512
```

Restart PHP:

```
brew services restart php@8.1
```

Verify your changes:

```
php -i | grep max_nesting_level
```

Will return:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 512 => 512
```

Answer (score 2):

This solves my problem:

"Xdebug has detected a possible infinite loop, and aborted your script with a stack depth of '256' frames"

Add to file:

/etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=512
```

And restart the server

Answer (score 2):

Solved for me by commenting in 20-xdebug.ini:
;zend_extension=xdebug.so

and conf xdebug in php.ini (from xdebug doc)
2. Add the following line to this PHP ini file:
zend_extension=xdebug

If Xdebug does not show up, or you get a warning from PHP that an xdebug.so file or similar was not found, you might need to use the full path instead of just zend_extension=xdebug, such as zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so

https://xdebug.org/docs/install

Answer (score 1):

**mac os: 13.4.1**

In the command line, type and check **max_nesting_level**

```
php -i | grep max_nesting_level
```

Go to the **/usr/local/etc/php/8.1/conf.d** folder

Find your **ext-xdebug.ini**, open and set like this:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=512
```

After that, restart php

```
brew services restart php@8.1
```

check again:

```
php -i | grep max_nesting_level
```

Will return:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 512 => 512
```

Refresh your page, enjoy :)